# Change column position in XamDataGrid at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, infragistics, xamdatagrid

I am working on **XamDataGrid** binded with the list of columns. I want to change the ***column position*** on the **XamDataGrid** on load using **MVVM**.
I have created the ***behavior*** of the **XamDataGrid**.

Can suggest solution according to my requirement?

Comment: Posted my answer and this works for me.

Answer (score 0):

This work for me:

```
  fieldLayout.Fields[columnlist[i]].ActualPosition = new FieldPosition(i, 0, 0, 0);
```